# Getting frame timestamp on RTSP playback

Tags: c++, qt, camera, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm making simple camera playback videoplayer on qt with gstreamer, it is possible to get frame date/time or only time from OSD? example of timestamp on picture, currently work with hikvision, tried to find it on RTP packets dumped with wireshark, but there is only relative to first frame timestamps.

[image: example of timestamp]